# Find the sum of the geometric series $(1+x)^r+(1+x)^{r+1}+\dots+(1+x)^n$ and hence show that $\sum_{i=r}^n\binom ir=\binom{n+1}{r+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

> Find the sum of the geometric series $(1+x)^r+(1+x)^{r+1}+\dots+(1+x)^n$ and hence show that $\sum_{i=r}^n\binom ir=\binom{n+1}{r+1}$

I haven't got any idea how to approach this question, how exactly are the two related.

Comment: The second is on pascals triangle, maybe draw it out, and write out a few terms. Once you get stuck in, you will forget the differences between the two.

Comment: Once you draw out the second equality, it may resemble a sports tool. The particular shape will also help you find literature on the subject.

Comment: Hint: what is the coefficient of $x^r$ in $(1+x)^r+ (1+x)^{r+1} + \cdots + (1+x)^n$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: $$s^r + s^{r+1} + \cdots + s^n = s^r (1 + s + s^2 + \cdots + s^{n-r}) = s^r \frac{s^{n-r+1} - 1}{s-1} = \frac{s^{n+1} - s^r}{s-1}$$ for $s \ge 0$. Apply this to your expression, and expand to the form $b_1 + b_2 x + b_2 x^2 + \cdots + b_n x^n$. What is $b_r$?

Hint 2: Expand $(1+x)^r + \cdots + (1+x)^n$ to the form $a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + \cdots + a_n x^n$. What is $a_r$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint :
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=r}^{n} R^k =\frac{R^{n+1}-R^k}{R-1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now consider the coeffiecient of $x^r$.